# The methods are considered most general/generally

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

sentence in question:

> The methods that are suggested by Paul and Gerald are considered most general.

In the sentence, I think that "most general" is very odd. Then, I adjusted it to "most generally" from "most general". But my teacher changed the word back to "most general".

Question: Is "most generally" incorrect? And, is "most general" correct?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use **general**.

In your sentence, *generally* would be an adverb (describes verbs), and *general* an adjective (describes nouns).

> I generally go to the gym at night.

In the above sentence, *generally* is used properly, as an adverb.

In this sentence, *most general* is meant to mean that the methods are **broad, widespread or sweeping.** It's not describing the *extent of the verb*, but rather it is describing the **methods**. So, in this situation *general* is an adjective.

---

Your sentence can be reduced as follows:

> 1. The methods are considered most **general**.

This means that **the methods themselves are** considered to be general (broad, widespread, widely applicable, etc.).

> 2. The methods are considered most **generally**.

This means that **the way in which we considered** these methods was general or broad. That is, our way of thinking about this was general, broad, in a broad context.

Of course, you probably meant to say that the methods were general (the first sentence); e.g., they were broad, or widespread, or applicable to lots of things, and so on.

Comment: So you're saying the sentence "The methods are considered most generally." is ungrammatical?

Comment: You could say something like: _The methods are considered most vital, generally._

Comment: Nope, that is *correct*, but is **not** the intended meaning of this sentence. Changing that to generally means it would be describing the **extent** of the verb. This sentence is saying that the methods are *general*, not that the methods are being considered in a general fashion. Putting the adverb at the end of this sentence is generally(hehe) an awkward use of the word.

Comment: That's the thing, though – you don't know the intended meaning, so both are okay. So maybe it would be nice if you explained it a bit (your rather subtle hints at that might be missed by the asker). Here, I'll try to edit your answer.

Comment: However you interpret it, it's an unusual and puzzling sentence. It's hard to know what the author means. Methods can be particular, unusual, scientific (or various other adjectives). To say that methods are general may be grammatical but it's not at all clear.

Comment: But if his teacher corrected it to say general, then we know for sure the authors intent was to say **general**, and not generally. Hence why my original answer explained that. I do like your edits though. Clarifies better.

Answer (score 1):

In science etc. one sees: **the methods suggested by A and B are considered to be very general in nature.**

Very is better than most here. That makes it easier to understand and read. Something is said in English: to be general in nature.

These questions are very general in nature.

That will get rid of the most/more problem. Most general in nature is OK, too but sounds a little bit old fashioned.

[most general in nature](https://www.slideshare.net/myotakustyle/definition-of-terms-59798301)